# SaaS platform for ecommerce?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, magento-community

I have already closed my online store on Magento Go. I'm looking for an alternative platform for my ecommerce business.

Comment: use Magento community it is free.

Comment: @ Ahmed El Awadi Thanks! I found that Magento community is free, but site development is quite expensive

Comment: Template from themeforest and few module(free or paid) and you are sorted :)

Comment: Total costs spent for launching Magento store highly depend on functionality, goals and so on.

Comment: Does your online store have some specific requirements (payment systems, integrations, etc.)?

Comment: I believe Magento Go already gave some options before closing its doors to users.  One being Big Commerce.  But I'm sure you can look around and find other ecommerce platforms like Volusion, Big Commerce, etc...